# How can I get a list of posts I have edited?

Tags: support, feature-request

How can I get a list of posts I have edited?.

It can be useful at times when the editor thinks later that some more information to the edit would have made the post better but unfortunately could not find which post he or she had edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of **all** edits is available [on your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/63095/boywholived?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

If you are specifically looking for posts **by others** that you edited, the query [Posts edited by the user, excluding own posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/173360/posts-edited-by-the-user-excluding-own-posts?UserId=63095) should help. (The results do not include very recent edits, since the Data Explorer is updated on weekends.)